# Twig {% if myId in myArray %} not checking for unique values?

Tags: twig

I have an ID that I need to check against an array of IDs.

When I do this:

```
{% if myId in myArray %}
```

it works if I'm checking for something like `'10'` in an array of '`10`,`'11'`,`'12'`. However, if I check for '1' in the same array of '10','11','12', it results in true since `'1'` is present in the values listed (`'0'` or '`2`' would also result as true in this case). Obviously I'm wanting this to result to false since the exact integer '`1`' is not actually present in the array.

Is there a way to have twig check for unique or exact integer values when using this function?

Comment: See https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L719 for the filter's internals.

Answer (score 1):

As Maerlyn pointed out to the source code on the in keyword of Twig, it is visible that your problem is caused by your values being strings.

Indeed twig considers '1' is present in '12' because he doesn't know '12' is an integer, it could also contrain 'number1' or any other string.

So the solution is to convert your array contents to integers first. Then send it to Twig.